# When giving 30 days notice for a rental contract in Spain, is the expression "el proximo dia" correct

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, españa

I live in Spain and have a rental contract. I would like to give notice. I need to give 30 days notice. Assume I want to leave the apartment on 30 April. I will give notice on 31 March.

This is the sentence I intend to write

*La devolución del inmueble y entrega de las llaves será puesta a su disposición **el próximo día** 30 de Avril 2024, a las 10:30 horas Calle Grande 1.*

Is the expression "el proximo dia 30 de April" correct as the day I leave the apartment would be 30 days in the future from the day that I give notice.

To me (and this is my question) the word "proximo" seems to indicate far fewer days. To me proximo seems to indicate something like immediately.

What would be the correct expression?

---

What I have tried

I looked up proximo on https://dle.rae.es/pr%C3%B3ximo?m=form

Here is a summary

1. adj. Cercano, que dista poco en el espacio o en el tiempo.
   Sin.:       cercano, vecino, inmediato, adyacente, allegado, contiguo, anexo, limítrofe, fronterizo.
   Ant.:   lejano, remoto.
2. adj. Siguiente, inmediatamente posterior. U. t. c. s.

Comment: It's piso, not inmeuble. Which is a [real estate] asset. próximo means next and is not needed. Entregaré el piso y las llaves el 30 de abril. Why sound like a real estate agent?

Comment: How do you know it's a whole "piso"? It might just be an "apartamento/departamento".

Comment: RAE 4. m. Conjunto de habitaciones que constituyen vivienda independiente en una casa de varias alturas.=apartamento = piso. Es comun decir esto en España, que yo sepa.

Comment: @Lambie es correcto el uso del término ‘inmueble’, es la palabra más versátil que se puede usar para referirse a una vivienda y es lo que todo el mundo usa en el ámbito legal. Inmueble. IN-MUEBLE. No se puede mover. Con eso está más que claro a qué se está refiriendo: el del contrato, porque sino cuál inmueble va a ser????¿?¿?¿?¿????¿??¿?¿?

Comment: En una carta informando un dueño de la intención de marcharse, no es necesario decir inmeuble. Una persona no alquila un inmeuble (a menos que es un negocio): una persona que alquila una vivienda, alquila un piso o apartamento. Inmueble es real estate, y aqui no estamos en real estate rental sino apartment rental. Aqui el ámbito *no es legal*. ¿Cuántos has alquilado en tu vida? Yo, muchos, por lo menos cinco...

Answer (score 5):

If we are in March 2024 and the surrender of the premises will take place in April 2024, "próximo" would be redundant. However, it is common usage in business jargon.

Sometimes, the adjective "corriente" (i.e. current) is used to avoid repeating the month or the year, in this case "2024".

I suggest changing the text "será puesta a su disposición" because, as written, it is unclear what it refers to.

Better:

La devolución del inmueble y la entrega de las llaves tendrán lugar el próximo 30 de abril de 2024, a las 10:30 AM, en Calle Grande 1.

or, using "corriente":

La devolución del inmueble y la entrega de las llaves tendrán lugar el 30 de abril del corriente año, a las 10:30 AM, en Calle Grande 1.

Comment: Parece una frase de un agente inmobiliario. No creo que un inquilino diria la cosa con un estilo tan formal. Entregaré el piso y las llaves el 30 de abril.

Comment: Sí, el estilo es muy contractual. Coincido en que sería más natural decir: Informo que devolveré el apartamento y las llaves el 30 de abril.

Comment: Al mejor no se da cuenta que no es necessario hablar como advogado.

Comment: Es una notificación formal; por tanto, no me parece incorrecto usar un lenguaje formal, sobre todo si no se tiene mucha confianza con el dueño del piso.